# how often that magento 2 reindex cron job run?

Tags: magento2, cron, reindex

Anyone know how often that Magento 2 Reindex Cron job run daily?

thanks

Comment: By default, it runs each minute

Answer (score 0):

To clarify comment

Yes every minute although there is logic to determine exactly what is indexed

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Indexer/etc/crontab.xml#L1-L20

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="index">
        <job name="indexer_reindex_all_invalid" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\ReindexAllInvalid" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="indexer_update_all_views" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\UpdateMview" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
        <job name="indexer_clean_all_changelogs" instance="Magento\Indexer\Cron\ClearChangelog" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```